# Generate XML from file in directory via PHP

Tags: php, xml, directory

I've got two folders images and big images with photos.

I want to generate an XML file with two attributes like this :

```
<images>
    <image source="images/image1" lightbox="bigimages/image1" />
    .....
</images>
```

I have something like this :

```
<?php

    // enter the path to the folder
    $path = "images/";


    // opendir
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

    // table photos
    $filetypes = array("jpg", "png");

    // forming xml
    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');


    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    // forming images

    $root = $doc->createElement('images');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {


        $file = rawurlencode($file);

        $split = explode(".", $file);
        $ext = strtolower($split[count($split)-1]);


        if (in_array($ext, $filetypes)) {

            // additional image
            $item = $doc->createElement("image");
            $item = $root->appendChild($item);


            $file = $path.$file;

            // adding an attribute source
            $item->setAttribute('source', $file);


        }


    }




    // closure
    closedir($dir_handle);

    // Save to XML
    $doc->save("plik.xml");
    echo "plik xml wygenerowany poprawnie!!!";
?>
```

And now the question is how to add second attribute with path to images from "bigimages" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$big_image = 'bigimages/' . basename($file);

if (file_exists($big_image)) {
    $item->setAttribute('source', $big_image);
}
```

See also: [basename()](http://www.php.net/basename)

Comment: it add some think like this
<image source="images/image1.jpg" lightbox="images1/"/>
I want to have lightbox="images1/image1.jpg

Any ideas and how to do it alphabetic from a to z??